# OpenCL header file not found

Tags: opencl

So please bear with me if the question is very trivial.

I wanted to install Intel implementation of OpenCL to code in integrated intel GPU.

I installed the OpenCL driver using Beignet. It successfully installed and clinfo shows the number of platforms and other details.

I have the following code,

```
#define CL_USE_DEPRECATED_OPENCL_1_2_APIS
#include <CL\cl.hpp>
#include<iostream>
int main() {
    std::vector<cl::Platform> platforms;
    cl::Platform::get(&platforms);
    std::cout << "Total platforms including cpu: " << platforms.size() << std::endl;
    if (platforms.size() == 0) {
        std::cout << " No platforms found. Check OpenCL installation!\n";
        exit(1);
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < platforms.size(); j++) {
        auto p = platforms[j];//Change platform from 0,1 and 2
        std::vector <cl::Device> devices;
        p.getDevices(CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, &devices);
        for (int i = 0; i < devices.size(); i++) {
            auto device = devices[i];
            auto vendor = device.getInfo<CL_DEVICE_VENDOR>();
            std::cout << vendor << std::endl;
            auto version = device.getInfo<CL_DEVICE_VERSION>();
        }
        std::cout << "----------------------\n";
    }
}
```

When I compile using $g++ -o test test.cpp -lOpenCL it throws the following error

```
fatal error: CL\cl.hpp: No such file or directory
 #include <CL\cl.hpp>
```

I linked the library as follows,

sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOpenCL.so /usr/local/lib/libOpenCl.so

I'm not sure how to proceed further. Please help

Comment: #include <CL/cl.hpp> (change the slash direction)?

Comment: You have the device specific drivers installed but you also need the OpenCL headers. They usually come in separate packages.

Comment: I recommend using CLEW instead of some SDK's headers https://github.com/martijnberger/clew